# How do I save google places location to django models?

Tags: django, google-maps, django-models, google-places-api, google-places

I am trying to create an app that relies heavily on location. I am using google  maps places api to allow users to select a location and add it to the database. My current issue is that I can't seem to figure out how to save the location from the google maps places JavaScript api to the database. For example Suzy chooses a store and wants to save the store and it's location to the database. I can't seem to figure out how to save the store location to the database. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far that didn't work?

Comment: Try to share some code and where your problem lies. Is it frontend or backend?

Comment: The only information from the places API you are allowed to store persistently per the Terms of Service is the place_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to save the longitude and latitude because they can denote the exact location globally, you can add fields something like

```
long = DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
lat  = DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
```

Since decimals are very important in coordinates but using more than 6 is basically meaningless.

Get the longitude and latitude with geolocation() [see this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)

```
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {

         let lat = position.coords.latitude;
         let long = position.coords.longitude;
         $("input[name='lat']").val(lat);
         $("input[name='lat']").val(long);
         let url_str = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+lat+','+long+'&key=yourkey'
        $.getJSON(url_str, function(data) {
              console.log(data);
              //here you get the location data, make more fields like street address, city in db and pass it to inputs and submit the form to save it.
          });
        }
```

Comment: Well it depends on the use case... OP question is too broad. You could store the coords but you could also store the Place ID as OP mentioned that user wants to save a "store" which in Google Maps is called a *place*. Or you could save both. So definitely not "the best way" but "one way".

Comment: Would that method allow me to filter search results based on proximity also?

Comment: And how would I go about getting the long and lat from the javascript api ?

Comment: @Osaro I updated the answer that can help you more, as MrUpsidedown said your question is too broad, try to do more research